# Spring - jpa one-to-many mapping

Tags: java, spring, jpa

First of all hello everybody, it's my first post here.
I'm very new at spring and have bit trouble to grasp mapping object to database. To be more specific, there is an article: 
[OneToMany](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany)

In given example there are 2 clases:

```
    @Entity
public class Employee {
  @Id
  @Column(name="EMP_ID")
  private long id;
  ...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner")
  private List<Phone> phones;
  ...
}

@Entity
public class Phone {
  @Id
  private long id;
  ...
  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="OWNER_ID")
  private Employee owner;
  ...
}
```

Can I place some annotation to make the table Employee have a column with list of phones?

Comment: No. That's not how relational databases work. You don't store several things in the same cell. That would make the data impossible to query. You need to study the basics of relational database design/normalization.

Comment: But above relationship can be written using ElementCollection as detailed in this post https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection

Comment: JPA is what maps an object to the database, not Spring.